# Missing Xcode 6 Docset

Tags: xcode6

I notice upon receiving Xcode6-Beta 4 that there's no documentation.
I'm particularly interested in iOS 8 documentation.

How do I get iOS 8 documentation for both Xcode & Dash?

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for Xcode 6 beta are in the package itself. Go to Xcode 6 in Finder, right click on it, 'Show Package Content', then go to Contents > Developer > Documentation > DocSets and double click the docset files to import them to Dash.

Comment: Okay...  So the original site of: ~/Library/Developer/Shared/Documentation/DocSets/ is invalid.

Comment: Just for reference on this question: The current location is `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Documentation/DocSets`.

Comment: just one addition to this answer. DocSets will show at that location despite not having been downloaded. So first go to XCode -> Preferences -> Components -> Documentation and download each